# ANR error related with MediaPlayer reported by Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: java, android, timeout, android-mediaplayer, crashlytics

I have used Firebase Crashlytics and the following ANR error is shown, I would appreciate any help as I have been trying to solve this error for many months ago and now I have added Crashlytics to my app to investigate more what could be generating the ANR error :

```
main (native): tid=1 systid=7666 
#00 pc 0x9a4a4 libc.so (__ioctl + 8)
#01 pc 0x6754f libc.so (ioctl + 30)
#02 pc 0x2f1b5 libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool) + 228)
#03 pc 0x2ff39 libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*) + 36)
#04 pc 0x2fce3 libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::transact(int, unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int) + 134)
#05 pc 0x2a577 libbinder.so (android::BpBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int) + 118)
#06 pc 0x4291f libmedia.so (android::BpMediaPlayerService::create(android::sp<android::IMediaPlayerClient> const&, audio_session_t, android::content::AttributionSourceState const&) + 430)
#07 pc 0x38b69 libmedia.so (android::MediaPlayer::setDataSource(int, long long, long long) + 220)
#08 pc 0x50e3f libmedia_jni.so (android_media_MediaPlayer_setDataSourceFD(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, long long, long long) + 146)
       at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java)
       at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1354)
       at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:1047)
       at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:1015)
       at com.dev.myapp.activityone.playMediaPlayer(activityone.java:65)
       at com.dev.myapp.activityone$15.onFinish(activityone.java:10)
       at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:142)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)




    public void playMediaPlayer(int id) {
            try {
                if (mediaPlayer != null || mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                }
    
                if (id == 1) {
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound1);
                } else if (id == 2) {
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound2);
    
                }
                if (PreferenceData.getSound(getApplicationContext())) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
        }

Thanks for the help
```